# sbt-proguard You have to specify '-keep' options for the shrinking step

Tags: sbt-proguard

I am struggling to get the sbt-proguard plugin to work. I have a class library that I want to obfuscate but I cannot seem to get the plugin to output without the above error. I have specified the keep option, or at lease I think that I have, but I have had no luck. I copied the keep options from the Proguard website which said it was meant for class libraries. In addition, I do not think the plug-in is responding the the options that I have configured.

For example, I wanted to have more verbose output to see if the output could give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong. However, whenever I look at the log files, it always specifies the default options. Below is my configuration. Can someone help me out with this one? I am completely lost. Thanks

```
import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard._

import ProguardKeys._


lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  Dependencies.Libraries.junit,
  Dependencies.Libraries.springBootLogging,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaMock,
  Dependencies.Libraries.joda,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaTestPlus,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaXml,
  Dependencies.Libraries.commonsCodec,
  Dependencies.Libraries.typeSafeConfig
)

val keepClasses =
  """
    |-injars       in.jar
    |-outjars      out.jar
    |-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
    |-printmapping out.map
    |
    |-keepparameternames
    |-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
    |-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
    |                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
    |
    |-keep public class * {
    |    public protected *;
    |}
    |
    |-keepclassmembernames class * {
    |    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    |    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
    |}
    |
    |-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    |    native <methods>;
    |}
    |
    |-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    |    public static **[] values();
    |    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    |}
    |
    |-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    |    static final long serialVersionUID;
    |    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    |    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    |    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    |    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    |    java.lang.Object readResolve();
    |}
  """.stripMargin

proguardSettings

lazy val skedaddleCore = (project in file(".")).
  settings(BuildSettings.buildSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "core",
    resolvers := Resolvers.all,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    merge in Proguard := true,
    proguardVersion in Proguard := "5.2.1",
    options in Proguard --= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings"),
    options in Proguard ++= Seq("-verbose", "-dontshrink"),
    options in Proguard += keepClasses
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the plugin to do what I wanted with the following configuration.

```
import sbt.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard._

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  Dependencies.Libraries.junit,
  Dependencies.Libraries.springBootLogging,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaMock,
  Dependencies.Libraries.joda,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaTestPlus,
  Dependencies.Libraries.scalaXml,
  Dependencies.Libraries.commonsCodec,
  Dependencies.Libraries.typeSafeConfig
)

proguardSettings

ProguardKeys.proguardVersion in Proguard := "5.2.1"

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings")

ProguardKeys.inputs in Proguard <<= (dependencyClasspath in Compile) map { _.files }

ProguardKeys.filteredInputs in Proguard <++= (packageBin in Compile) map ProguardOptions.noFilter

val keepClasses =
  """
    |-keepparameternames
    |-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
    |                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
    |
    |-keep,includedescriptorclasses interface com.** {
    |    <methods>;
    |}
  """.stripMargin

ProguardKeys.options in Proguard += keepClasses

lazy val skedaddleCore = (project in file(".")).
  settings(BuildSettings.buildSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "core",
    resolvers := Resolvers.all,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )
```